# Force function to implement interface

Tags: typescript

Wouldn't it be cool if there was a way to ensure a typescript function uses all of its input parameters?

Example I'm writing database queries as functions for my backend application to use, and would like every `find` query to implement `SELECT` functionality.

```
// Params shared across all Find queries.
interface FindQueryParams {
  select?: string // which columns to select.
};

// Params for the specific function, extending Shared Params.
interface FindUserParams extends FindQueryParams {
  userId: number // id of the user.
}
function findUser(params: FindUserParams){
  const user = ...
  ... // code to find the user.
  return user;
}
```

I want to ensure that the method uses the `select` parameter passed into it and Typescript to complain if my function does not user `params.select`.

There is no way to make sure function uses it without using classes as far as I know.

Comment: How would you ensure that using a class?

Comment: Maybe you can write a custom eslint rule